# Counting backwards from a date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count back from the start of a new academic quarter. I am tracking when students are registering and want to compare how many days before the quarter starts. The first day of the quarter isn't always the same. I have a date table in the central database that lists every date, what quarter it's in, with a flag for the first day.

So here is a simplified table of what I'm trying to do.

```
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| Date      | Quarter | First Day Flag | Days before quarter |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/1/2020  | Q1      | Y              | 0                   |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/2/2020  | Q1      | N              | -5                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/3/2020  | Q1      | N              | -4                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/4/2020  | Q1      | N              | -3                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/5/2020  | Q1      | N              | -2                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/6/2020  | Q1      | N              | -1                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/7/2020  | Q2      | Y              | 0                   |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/8/2020  | Q2      | N              | -5                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/9/2020  | Q2      | N              | -4                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/10/2020 | Q2      | N              | -3                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/11/2020 | Q2      | N              | -2                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/12/2020 | Q2      | N              | -1                  |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1/13/2020 | Q3      | Y              | 0                   |
+-----------+---------+----------------+---------------------+
```

I need code to generate the fourth column that counts backward from the first day of the quarter.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) might be what you are looking for

Comment: What you are considering as a quarter is a week. Also please go through [Minimal reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post an attempt at what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is just dummy data--the real quarters are 10 weeks with changing dates. (Sorry I didn't post an attempt--this is my first post and I am truly stuck on where to begin.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create table #temp(Dates Date,Quarters char(2)
,FirstDayFlag char(1), DaysBeforeQuarter int)

insert into #temp values
('1/1/2020','Q1','Y'  ,null  )
,('1/2/2020','Q1','N' ,null  )     
,('1/3/2020','Q1','N' ,null  )    
,('1/4/2020','Q1','N' ,null  )    
,('1/5/2020','Q1','N' ,null  )
,('1/6/2020','Q1','N' ,null  )
,('1/7/2020','Q2','Y' ,null  )
,('1/8/2020','Q2','N' ,null  )
,('1/9/2020','Q2','N' ,null  )
,('1/10/2020','Q2','N',null  )
,('1/11/2020','Q2','N',null  )
,('1/12/2020','Q2','N',null  )
,('1/13/2020','Q3','Y',null  )


update T
set DaysBeforeQuarter=case when t.FirstDayFlag='Y' 
then 0 else datediff(day,t1.dates,t.dates) end 
from #temp t
cross apply(select top 1 dates 
from #temp t1 where t1.FirstDayFlag='Y'
and t1.Dates>t.dates)t1

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Comment: Thank you! That gave me the idea of where to start and I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help with this! Your suggestions gave me a place to start, and I got it to work!

Here is my code that seems to be working.

```
SELECT
d.CalendarDate as [Date]
,d.AcademicYrQtrCode as [Quarter]
,d.BeginInd as [FirstDayIndicator]
,CASE WHEN d.BeginInd = 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF (d, d2.CalendarDate, d.CalendarDate) END

FROM DateTable d

JOIN (SELECT * FROM DateTable d WHERE d.BeginInd = 'Y') d2
ON CONVERT (int, d.AcademicYrQtrCode) = CONVERT (int, d2.AcademicYrQtrCode) - 1
```

Comment: `JOIN (SELECT * FROM DateTable d WHERE d.BeginInd = 'Y') d2
ON CONVERT (int, d.AcademicYrQtrCode) = CONVERT (int, d2.AcademicYrQtrCode) - 1`. Output may be correct.You will suffer performance when there will be more records.This is fetching unnecessary lot of rows.Beside other demerit.